# JS Context Menu that works with KendoUI grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, contextmenu, kendo-grid

I have been trying to integrate various plugins with kendoUI to get a working right click menu on a grid.
It's been 3 days now, and i find that all of them have some issues, some don't work with grids some don'e work with IE10.

Does anyone know of a plugin or implementation i that works with kendoUI grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken a look at https://github.com/insanio/kendoui.ex?  There seems to be a context menu extension there for KendoUI.